# Note-taking app with a "forum-like" interface

Tags: open-source, note-taking, macos, journal

I've tried many apps for my notes and every one of them has some limitations.

The best experience I've had was using a forum! A simple forum like this: https://obsproject.com/forum/. I just open a new thread when I want to write about a certain argument, and I can post each time I want and posts are grouped by pages. I can use rich text, markdown, insert images, videos.

Basically this is what works for me, but I could use a forum only for a certain hobby of mine, I would like to use it for everything but of course I can't just post every thing of my life in a forum.

Does someone knows a way to have a "personal" forum or an app that resembles one? Also please notice that I don't want my content to be published on the internet or hosted somewhere that is not on my computer.

Also please notice I would like a user-friendly option, I'm not IT engineer, I'm just trying to have the optimal way of storing my notes.

#### TL;DR: Requirements

An app/service that allow me to write notes (posts) inside a folder (threads) and that displays all my notes in continuous pages that have ~25 notes per page, like a forum thread.

The problem of all note-taking apps is that multiple notes are not displayed on the same window, if I want to read my notes I have to click the first, read it, click the second, read it and so on... A forum is more convenient because you have many notes (usually 25) one after the other on a single page (where with notes I mean posts).

Comment: You do realise that they will all have some limitations. Please list all your requirements here, instead of expecting people to go to a forum.  Also, the three notes apps I have tried, you just start a new topic.

Comment: I've updated my question as requested.

Comment: At the end I went with a personal Discord server. If someone knows better please advise. Thank's.